# Forward syslog stream using Splunk Forwarder

Tags: splunk

How can I forward syslog stream using Splunk Universal Forwarder?

I have a centos7 system, and I want to forward the stream eg. localx without having to write it to disk.
Currently, I am only able to forward if I write the stream to disk and configure the forwarder to consume the file.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want syslog written to disk? That's definitely not a good practice (let alone how far from "best practice" it is). As @RichG stated, if you have the UF involved, it *must* get written to disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using the UF then writing to disk is the way.

If you want to avoid writing to disk and are open to a non-UF solution, then consider Splunk Connect for Syslog (SC4S).  It's a docker app that receives syslog streams and sends them to Splunk HEC inputs.  See https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/4740/ for more information.